# Is it possible (How) to have an application return custom search results in iPhone's spotlight search?

Tags: iphone, search, spotlight

I am working on making an application that will store information, and for user convenience I'd like to make it possible for them to use Spotlight (scroll to the left until search appears on the home screen) to search for items in the app.

Is this possible, and if so, can you point me to a reference? I have had no luck in finding this, but the iPod app implements it, (Undocumented API perhaps?)

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported on current versions of iOS, sadly. Please file a radar asking for this!
<[Bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com/)>